# T-SQL to "Merge" two rows, or "Rekey" all FK relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a production database where occasionally redundant rows in a single table need to be "Merged".

Let's assume that both rows in this table have identical values, except their IDs.

```
Table "PrimaryStuff"
ID | SomeValue
1  | "I have value"
2  | "I have value"
3  | "I am different"
```

Let's also assume that a number of related tables exist.  Because duplicates were created in the "PrimaryStuff" table, often rows are created in these child tables that SHOULD all be related to a single record on the PrimaryStuff table.  **The number and names of these tables are not under my control and should be considered dynamically at runtime.** IE: I don't know the names or even the number of related records, as other people may edit the database without my knowledge.

```
Table "ForeignStuff"
ID | PrimaryStuffId | LocalValue
1| 1| "I have the correct FK"
2| 1| "I have the correct FK"
3| 2| "I should get pointed to an FK of 1"
```

To resolve the duplication of PrimaryStuff's row 1 and 2, I wish to have ALL related tables change their FK's to 1s and then delete the PrimaryStuff's row 2.  This *SHOULD* be trivial, as if PrimaryStuff's row 1 didn't exist, I could just update the Primary Key on Row 2 to 1, and the changes would cascade out. I cannot do this because that would be a duplicate key in the PrimaryStuff's unique index.

Feel free to ask questions and I'll try to clear up anything that's confusing.

Comment: You're somewhat lucky to have integer PK's. I'd love to see an answer that also works with composite PK's involving a GUID, in a table that doesn't have a `DateInserted` column...

Comment: Actually, this is just the trivial example. My actual production DB uses GUIDs for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lets get a list of the rows that need to be updated (as I understand it you want the lowest ID to replace all the higher IDs)

```
 SELECT MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY SomeValue ORDER BY SomeValue, ID ASC) AS FirstID,
        ID,
        SOMEVALUE
 FROM PrimaryStuff
```

We can remove the ones where FirstID and ID match, these don't matter

```
SELECT FirstID, ID FROM
(
 SELECT MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY SomeValue ORDER BY SomeValue, ID ASC) AS FirstID,
        ID,
        SOMEVALUE
 FROM PrimaryStuff
) T
WHERE FirstID != ID
```

Now we have a change list.  We can use this in an update statement, put it in a temp table (or a CTE as I did below):

```
WITH ChangeList AS
(
  SELECT FirstID, ID FROM
  (
   SELECT MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY SomeValue ORDER BY SomeValue, ID ASC) AS FirstID,
        ID
   FROM PrimaryStuff
  ) T
  WHERE FirstID != ID
)
UPDATE ForeignStuff
SET PrimaryStuffId = ChangeList.FirstID
FROM ForeignStuff
JOIN ChangeList ON ForeignStuff.ID = ChangeList.ID
```

NB - Code not tested, might have typos.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hogan. You're right on track. You did miss the fly in the ointment though and it's a noodle scratcher:

How can I handle "n" ForeignStuff tables, where "n" represents an unknown number of tables like ForeignStuff that contain a foreign Key to the PrimaryStuff table.

Comment: @OliverKane - Just run the script for each table, or if you need to automate write a dynamic SQL using the above as a template.  (In this case you might want to use a temp table instead of a CTE to improve performance over multiple queries.)

Comment: @OliverKane - In case you did not understand, my solution does not care about the ForeignStuff tables till I go to modify them -- before that I'm just "getting ready".

Comment: Actually I just finished cobbling together a sproc based on your work that does just that.  Answer awarded to you kind sir.

Comment: @OliverKane - glad to be of help

Comment: that some serious sql

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier - True.  Here is some SQL which is not serious -> `INSERT MONKEY INTO BARREL WHERE FUN < (SELECT TOTAL(FUN) FROM BARREL)`

Answer (score 1):

Could you be more proactive and either use the existing ID when SomeValue already exists and enforce a unique constraint on PrimaryStuff.SomeValue, or why not make SomeValue the primary key of PrimaryStuff.  With it as the PrimaryKey then you would only ever add a record to PrimaryStuff if SomeValue did not already exist in it.

Lastly, and most simply, if SomeValue is always arbitrarily defined by others and you take whatever they give you, why not just drop PrimaryStuff altogether and let users enter whatever they wish into ForeignStuff?  If you need a unique listing for SomeValue, create a view based on your main table.  If you need to speed up querying then add an index to ForeignStuff.SomeValue field.

Here's an (untested) view when there are multiple tables like ForeignStuff:

```
-- dynamically generate a distinct list of values of interest
select SomeValue from ForeignStuffA
union select SomeValue from ForeignStuffB
union select SomeValue from ForeignStuffC
-- and so on, the union applies distinct
```

Comment: In the real world example, we import our data from a 3rd party on a 24 hour basis. Their application preforms this "Merge" operation, and since our local datastore mimics this, we need to be able to behave similarly. Since their backing is NoSQL, they don't have nearly the difficulty as we do on our end.

Also, the "duplicate rows" aren't actually duplicated. They are NEAR duplicates, usually produced when someone fatfingers data-entry. I am blessed enough to be given a mapping of "OldId->NewId" for each import.

Comment: On the right track though. Looking for something a bit more akin to what Hogan posted.  Also, keep in mind that ForeignStuff* names are not known at design time of the query.

Comment: Well that's a horse of a different color. I would suggest go nosql with them or mimic it as close as possible within the constraints of a relational database (e.g. forget the primarystuff table because it's incidental and not needed in the case you describe...except that you thought that relational dbs might have a cascade update/delete behavior they do not).  Creating a view won't work, but you could generate an similar query at runtime within your code.

Comment: I sadly cannot choose NoSQL (Though I wish I could as I love RavenDB).

So if I understand you correctly, even though I have a primary table which represents the users, that's an incorrect model because the actual primary table is in a foreign database?  I'd agree, though I'm hesitant to throw out all the internal relationships to this table. Besides this use case, it behaves as if it was native.

Comment: Aside, if you haven't already you may want to look up DDD concepts like context maps, bounded contexts, anti-corruption layers, conformist so as to be aware of the trade offs of being downstream from others output and what may be best for your situation.

Comment: Does the producer of your data provide you with the value of ID in PrimaryStuff, or are you generating that?

Comment: Cool! I increasingly find myself dealing with just such situations. Thanks for the aside.

Comment: The producer provides the ID. They also provide the merge mapping. We have a script spin up a read-only copy of their database each night on our local servers and I run update methods against that. It's inelegant, but due to the security around the data (HIPPA nonsense) methods with greater connectivity and less latency are not available.

The Producer acts as the primary datastore. They receive records from a variety of sources. My application's job is to document activity pertaining to users...even though the primary identifier of these users changes.

Comment: Back to the aside, I've found that searching for DDD info on the internet is hit and miss, and very misleading sometimes, but the book Domain Driven Design by Eric Evans is well worth the time and money and will make a lot of the resources online meaningful or ignorable because you'll know it's just their poorly worded opinion.

Comment: If the producer is providing the ID then keep it, and you are right that Hogan has your solution but...  This is a tricky situation, one person's typo could be another's intention and a machine can't determine that. I'd be careful what information is thrown out. Also lookup Entities vs. Value-Objects in DDD.  That should help you think this through.  It sounds like this merge thing may be unjustified and even dangerous, or the value of ID makes no difference at all.  You'll have to answer that.