# c# EntityFramework Reassign All children to new parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853771/t-sql-to-merge-two-rows-or-rekey-all-fk-relationships)

I'm trying to come up with a way to reassign all child tables to another parent table. I am currently using EntityFramework 5 to interact with my database.  While it won't necessarily be as efficient using EF, this operation rarely occurs.

That said, to do a basic change of a parent object using EntityFramework is straight forward:

```
objChild.Parent = objNewParent;
```

When SaveChanges() is called, the Foreign Key is properly updated.

How can I get ALL related entities so I can iterate over them to assign the new parent object?  I know this will require Reflection, but so far I've been unable to cobble together anything usable.

I am not concerned with performance. Number of calls to the database, total volume of data loaded, memory or cpu use is not relevant to this answer.  They key is the generic nature of not knowing which tables will be present.

Basically, I'm trying to do this but for ALL related records, rather than a single type:

```
var sourceParents = ParentRecords.Where(n => sourceIds.Contains(n.Id));
var targetParent =  Participants.Find(targetId);
var childRecords =  sourceParents.SelectMany(n => n.ChildRecords).ToArray();

foreach (var child in childRecords) {
    child.ParentRecord = targetParent;
}
```

Comment: This is going to be difficult. If you're working with fewer than ~10 tables I would say it would be easier to just write a bunch of boilerplate methods to perform all the mappings. If it's more than that, I would probably update the T4 templates so they create an `UpdateRelationships` method for each table; within the T4 template you can use the EDM API to find the relationships for each table. I would not recommend trying to write a reflection-based generic method unless generating the code in T4 is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that LINQ usually involves a smaller amount of code tends to be misunderstood as delivering a more efficient solution.

What your current code does:

- One iteration through `ParentRecords` to get the list of parents ->
  `var sourceParents = ParentRecords.Where(n =>
  sourceIds.Contains(n.Id));`
- One iteration through `sourceParents` to get the list of children -> `sourceParents.SelectMany(n => n.ChildRecords).ToArray();`
- One iteration through `childRecords` to change the parent for each children -> `foreach...`

As far as the first two iterations refer to the same objects (although to different sub-elements), your code can be reduced to just two loops:

```
 var targetParent = Participants.Find(targetId);
 foreach (var parent in ParentRecords)
 {
     if (parent == null) continue;
     if (sourceIds.Contains(parent.Id))
     {
         //Assigning the new parent to all the children
         foreach (var child in parent.ChildRecords)
         {
             if (child == null) continue;
             child.ParentRecord = targetParent;  
         }
     }
 }
```

I don't think that you can do things faster under the current conditions (other than by moving to more efficient `Types`, relying on approaches maximising the hardware-resources or changing the input data structure to allow more efficient update operations). In case of having a function on the lines of `update_the_parents_for_all_my_records()`, bear in mind that it would basically do the same thing: iterate through all the elements. Small-code-size approaches can be fine under certain conditions but tend to be less adaptable than big-code ones. In any case, they shouldn't be misunderstood: the length of the code is not directly related to its actual efficiency (i.e., what the code is actually doing in each case).

Comment: I apperciate the answer, but I'm not angling for efficiency. This occurs so very seldom that it's a non-issue.

What is important that the line that reads:
foreach (var child in parent.ChildRecords)

Can be for ALL child records, not only one of a specific type.  This will almost certainly involve Reflection, or another (more advanced than me) mechanism.

I'll upvote, because your answer indeed is accurate and useful, but it's not what I'm asking. 

As far as SQL vs EntityFramework is concerned, I would certainly accept and answer in T-SQL which accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: @OliverKane Thanks. Bear in mind that this code delivers exactly the same than your original one. It retrieves all the ChildRecords of each (relevant) parent one. These loops represents a bigger-code version of your LINQ query. Example: if you have parent1 (child1, child2, child3), parent2 (child4, child5, child6) and you want to set a new parent (parent3) for all these children, this code will do it.

Comment: @OliverKane there is nothing "more advanced" which can do something a loop cannot do. What I intended to explain in my answer is precisely that these more advanced, shorted-code approaches are no more than a shortcut to what really is the base for everything (loops and conditions). Some times, these short-code references might seem to deliver something else, but they don't. "Reflection", for example, might be useful on very specific conditions but, in general, represents a quite slow approach to almost any problem. Perhaps I haven't understood what you are after properly...

Comment: perhaps I've phrased my question body poorly. In particular, I'm looking how to iterate over a set of child Entities that represent multiple Types.  If a ParentRecord has a collection of ARecords, BRecords, and CRecords, I'm looking for the way to get that collection, and then assign a new parent for each.  What you are saying is accurate, and is certainly a better re-write of what I'm intending, but it does not solve the generic case of an arbitrary, runtime determined set of child entities.  Does that make sense? If not, I can try to rephrase.

Comment: Just a moment. I'll try to draw what I'm attempting to achieve.

Comment: @OliverKane OK. This makes plently of sense but it would be better to understand the exact variables/relationships you are looking for.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37965/discussion-between-oliver-kane-and-varocarbas)